# Possible to Use Json Data in a Join Clause?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have some tracking data and since some of the data changes between "events" I am storing it as a JSON in a column in SQL Server.

I have this

```
{"items":[{"ids":[51130]}
```

Now this has the item id. I now want to get the information of the "item" but I am not sure how to do this as I would need some joins.

If I was doing this with regular joins I would have something like this

```
SELECT        *
FROM            Brands INNER JOIN
                         Items ON Brands.Id = Items.BrandId
                         Events ON Events.ItemId = Items.Id
                 where Items.Id in (51130)
```

**Sample Data**

```
Brands
1   Apple
2   Samsung

Items
id  name description brandId
51130 Galaxy 10  "Smartphone"  2

Event
id Details 
1  {"items":[{"ids":[51130]}]
```

Comment: Any boolean expression is allowed.  You would need to extract the fields you want to compare.

Comment: the json is on the Events Table (in a column called details). Brands and Items is where the information of the "item" lives, so the "id" is primary key of Items.

Comment: I added some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand this correctly. You need to parse the JSON, stored in `details` column and return the content as a table using `OPENJSON()`. The next example demonstrates how to use `OPENJSON()` with one table (note, that the JSON in the question is not correct):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Events (
   id int, 
   details nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Events (id, details)
VALUES (1, N'{"items":[{"ids":[51130]}]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT id, itemId
FROM Events
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(details, '$.items[0].ids') WITH (itemId int '$')
```

Result:

```
----------
id  itemId
----------
1   51130
```

For complex statements, you may try to use the appropriate joins to get the expected results.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Brands (
   brandId int,
   brandName nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Brands
   (BrandId, BrandName)
VALUES
   (1, N'Apple'),
   (2, N'Samsung')
CREATE TABLE Items (
   id int,
   name nvarchar(50),
   description nvarchar(50),
   brandId int
)   
INSERT INTO Items
   (id, name, description, brandId)
VALUES
   (51130, N'Galaxy 10', N'Smartphone', 2)
CREATE TABLE Events (
   id int, 
   details nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Events 
   (id, details)
VALUES
   (1, N'{"items":[{"ids":[51130]}]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Brands b
INNER JOIN Items i ON b.brandId = i.BrandId
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, itemId
   FROM Events
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(details, '$.items[0].ids') WITH (itemId int '$') 
) e ON i.id = e.itemId
```

Result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
brandId brandName   id      name        description brandId id  itemId
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2       Samsung     51130   Galaxy 10   Smartphone  2       1   51130
```

Answer (score 0):

For begin, i suppose you use sql's own logic to insert json.

To retrieve the data you want, must use this function

```
JSON_VALUE("yourjsoncolumn", '$.yourjson.atribute') = 51130
```

In this article have full explanation to resolve your problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: yes it's my own logic to insert, but I now need to get the details of the "items" now hence why It hink I need a join clause. I also may have "1" id or 100 ids to look up so I want to try to do it all in one go if possible hence why my where clause has an "in clause"

Comment: Let me see if I got it...
Do you have the Items table that contains the items that are in the details column of the Event table, which in this case would be json's items but has nothing to do with the Event and Items table ID?